# In a hosted ASP.NET MVC web application, Excel import is failing frequently

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ms-access-2007

I have an error in uploading Excel files to an ASP.NET MVC web application which is hosted in Azure. An issue occurs with OLEDB 12 not being registered on local machine frequently. When I reinstall the MS Access 2007 database engine, the error disappears for a while, but the issue pops up again after some time.

I already tried with newer versions of MS Access database engine, but it's not working.

Comment: Please show us the **full and exact** error message you're getting ....

Comment: MicroSoft OLEDB 12.00 is not Registered on local Machine